# Rails counting children of children

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is probably really easy. I have the following models:

- Foo has many Bars
- Bars have many Marflars

And I want to find out how many Marflars a given Foo has

I thought it would be easy. I've tried the following but it causes some funny things to happen:

```
@foo = Foo.find(params[:id])
@bars = @foo.bars
@marflars = []
@bars.each do |bar|
  @marflars << bar.marflars
end
```

Whats the easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading them all and processing them that way is extremely inefficient and will not work if you have large amounts of data. Instantiating every single thing as a model just to count them is extremely wasteful.

Instead, you can query this:

```
Foo.includes(bars: :marflars).pluck('COUNT(*)')
```

That should render out a double join to compute the final set.